# Selecionar span, e pegar o texto que há dentro

Tags: html, .net, vb.net, parse

Eu tenho o seguinte código HTML:

```html
<div class="dados">

<span><strong>Nome:</strong> Yuri Santos</span>
<span><strong>E-mail:</strong> email@hotmail.com</span>

<span><strong>Endereço:</strong> Rua treze</span>

<span><strong>Cidade:</strong> Dos Sonhos</span>

</div>
```

E usando um `WebBrowser` eu quero pegar os valores que estão dentro de um determinado `span`.

Porém, eu quero selecionar quais são, ex: Nome, Email.

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
For Each h As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
        If Not Object.ReferenceEquals(h.GetAttribute("className"), Nothing) AndAlso h.GetAttribute("className").Equals("dados") Then
            txtDados.Text = h.InnerText
            Exit For
        End If
   Next
```

Porém, ele pega todos os valores (nome, email, endereço, cidade).

Como eles não tem `ID` ou `nome`, eu não sei como identificá-los para pegar somente os que eu quero.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 1):

Não use o `WebBrowser` isto é um renderizador de páginas e você não precisa disto. Ou use o [`WebClient`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0) ou melhor ainda use a biblioteca [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/) que faz isto de forma mais apropriada.

Estas ferramentas irão ajudar mas você tem que fazer um pouco de "trabalho braçal". O que você terá a disposição é uma estrutura de dados mais organizada e mais fácil de filtrar.

Comment: Ok, vou pesquisar sobre.
Obrigado.